# Java deadlock: are there cases where it is not a bug?

Tags: java, tomcat, lucene, deadlock

I took a thread dump of a Java program, and it said `Found one Java-level deadlock`.

Can I confidently affirm that there is a bug in this program?

To me, it sounds like a [deadlock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/deadlock.html) is a programming problem, and the only solution is to fix the source code.
Am I wrong? Are there circumstances where a deadlock is a normal part of the program's execution, and the deadlock eventually somehow disappears?

It is a rather conventional Java web application with hundreds of users. The two threads that are waiting for each other seem to be one [Tomcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat) request worker and one [Lucene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucene) indexing job, both using `sun.misc.Unsafe.park`. As far as I know, the program does not have any thread monitoring meta-sophistication.

Comment: +1 I'm curious to hear about this.  Every case of deadlock I've heard of has been a bug, but there might be an example where it isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are there circumstances where a deadlock is a normal part of the program's execution, and the deadlock eventually somehow disappears?

In theory yes, depending on the kind of deadlock.

For example, if two threads are `Object.wait()` deadlocked, one of the wait calls could time out (eventually).  Alternatively, a third thread could break the deadlock by calling `Thread.interrupt()` on one of the deadlocked threads.  This might be done as a deliberate deadlock-breaking strategy, or for some other reason.

On the other hand, a deadlock on a acquiring primitive mutexes won't ever go away of its own accord, and cannot be broken short of calling one of the deprecated Thread stop/kill methods.  And if you do that, you are liable to leave data structures in an intermediate state, making it problematic to continue after breaking the lock.

---

The key thing to look for is whether the blocking action is interruptible; e.g. whether it can throw an `InterruptedException` or similar.

Comment: I would argue that if you use an operation that times out (`Object.wait` has such an overload, as do various higher-level constructs), then it's not a deadlock, since at least one operation is  not only depending on the other to finish (it's waiting for that _or_ for a timeout).

Comment: @yshavit - you could argue that, but what if the timeout is deliberately set to a huge value; e.g. `Thread.sleep(Integer.MAX_VALUE)` with the intention of creating an interruptable wait that won't time out.  The point is that effect could be the same whether or not this is a "deadlock" according to your definition.

Comment: Then it wouldn't be a deadlock, but it would still be a bad bug -- an effective deadlock, you could call it, but not a real one. But the question wasn't "are things that aren't technically deadlocks but are effectively similar, always bugs," which could be a trickier question (how close is close enough?). I can't think of any situation in which a _true_ deadlock -- ain't nothin gonna release them circularly-dependent resources -- is anything but a bug in production. (I could imagine a lazily written test creating deadlock to prove, in a third test, that the deadlocked threads hang.)

Comment: @yshavit - Let me say this plainly. I think you are splitting hairs.  Unless the OP chimes in to say that he is *only* interested in deadlocks that conform to your definition of a deadlock, the fine distinction you are making is not relevant to the Question.

Comment: @yshavit, Stephen: Sorry for not precising. Let's say a deadlock is something that appears as `Found one Java-level deadlock` when running a Java thread dump on HotSpot with KILL -3.

Answer (score 0):

It is kind of like an exception (albeit a very disgusting and ugly one :) ) : if you are prepared to handle deadlocks, because they can happen in your application (for example you're writing a DB server in java) then there's nothing wrong with them.

That said, for the majority of cases it's *really* a bug, like the unchecked exception, the dreaded NPE :(